# React native: "only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views"

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-svg

[image]pressing the button to get the base64 string of the svg ... produces the following error:
- Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

```
render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
        <Svg
          ref={c => (this.svg = c)}
          height="50%"
          width="50%"
          viewBox="0 0 100 100"
        >
          <Circle
            cx="50"
            cy="50"
            r="45"
            stroke="blue"
            strokeWidth="2.5"
            fill="green"
          />
        </Svg>

        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            this.svg.toDataURL(data => {
              console.log("data", data);
            });
          }}
        >
          <Text>Get Data</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
```

Any help?

Comment: which thread is calling this `render()` ?

Comment: in a very simple app ... in app.js

Comment: [mcve] and please post the entire stacktrace so that people can help you.
pasting one method and a big screenshot is really of no help to anyone.

from the thing you posted so far, i'd guess that you're trying to create views from a non-UI (not main) thread which is a problem in android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out ...

It was npm (v 6.4.1) issue, cause when I removed node-modules folder and package-lock.json and tried to install it back using yarn, it worked like before.

I installed a newer version of react-native-svg, which does not work for me, when I tried to downgrade to an older version using npm, for some reason it does not recognize it, and package-lock.json kept creating with the newer version i uninstalled!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I solved it by literally running my block on the main thread:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // My block, doing stuff on the view
    }
});
```